# Finding probability

Tags: python, probability

I am trying to find out how I would work out the odds for the results in a coin toss simulator. There is a 50% chance of heads and a 50% of tails.
How would I go about working out the odds of the result it returns happening?
Here is my code:

```
import random
head = 0
tail = 0
length  = int(input('How many coins do you want to flip? '))
for i in range(length):
    side = random.randint(0, 1)
    if side == 1:
        head = head + 1
    else:
        tail = tail + 1
print('There where ' + str(tail) + ' tails and ' + str(head) + ' heads')
```

Comment: Do you want to measure the probability of you getting the same amount of heads and tails given the number of simulations?

Comment: say you flip it ten times i want it to tell you the probability of the amount of tails it gives, then for the amount of heads

Comment: You want me to tell you: there is p1 probability that there will be 1 tail, p2 that there will be two tails... ?

Comment: Or you want to know what was the probability of the result that you have got in the simulation?

Comment: You make a simulation, flip a coin ten times and get 4 heads. You want to know what is the probability of getting those 4 heads?

Comment: @Fulaphex yes, that's right

Answer (score 2):

Probabilities of the result that you have got in the simulation can be printed like this:

```
print('Tail: ' + str(float(tail) / length) + ' Head ' + str(float(head)/length))
```

Comment: This shows the percentage of each result (heads/tails), not the chances of getting that particular result.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate such probability you should use binomial coefficient. [image] - this gives you all possible combinations of h heads and t tails. Divide it with all possible combinations which are [image] and you get your probability.

To get the factorial function, the exclamation mark, you can write:

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return n * fact(n-1)
```

This will work for all positive numbers. If you want to speed it up, you can have a dictionary that will allow you to memorise previous calls. That would be:

```
_d = {0:1}
def fact(n):
    if n in _d: return _d[n]
    _d[n] = n * fact(n-1)
    return _d[n]
```

Comment: How would i get the exclamation mark in python, i understand how it works, but is isn't reconised